# Не входит в админ панель OpenCart

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, opencart

Суть в том, что страница просто перезагружается и никакой реакции.
При попытке востановить пароль - тоже самое.

Хотя на `OpenServer` работает без проблемно.

Что может вызывать такую ошибку?

Сайт [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://hot-store.com.ua/admin/)

Comment: Так у вас на кнопке "Войти" стоит url /login, вот и редиректит назад

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/213987)

Comment: может дело в том что action="http://  а сайт на https ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

На кнопке "войти" я исправил http на https и вошел.